# css flexbox IE11 flex item content breaks out of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Managed to get a flexbox layout work in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera.

Would like to make this work in IE11, or know for sure that it is not possible.

I have read about IE11 issues and tried setting height 100% on the container, without success. IE11 content overflows vertically all containers except body.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.header,
.footer {
  height: 2em;
  flex: none;
  background-color: orange;
}
.content-wrapper {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
}
.main {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em 1em 0;
  min-width: 12em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
}
.main-body {
  flex: 1 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.main-toc {
  order: -1;
  background-color: green;
}
.nav {
  order: -1;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 12em;
}
pre {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  header
</header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <main id="main" role="main" class="main">

      <div id="main-body" class="main-body">

        <h1>H1</h1>

        <p><a href="#">link</a>
        </p>

        <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation ...</p>

        <pre><code class="language-php">
public function publicMethodOptionalParam($p1 = null)
{
    return true;
}
</code></pre>

        <p>On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation ...</p>

      </div>

      <div id="main-toc" class="main-toc">
        table of contents
      </div>

    </main>

    <nav id="nav" role="navigation" class="nav">

      <ul>
        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="is-active">Getting Started
          <ul>
            <li class="is-active"><a href="/getting-started/introduction/">Introduction</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  footer
</footer>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/emilkm/pen/pyVWWo) with the above code

Comment: Seems you just need `flex: 1 0 auto;` on the .content css class. [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNmazg)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Works in IE11 now.

Comment: @michaPau, please provide a proper answer so that the question can be resolved.

Comment: Good rule of thumb is to always set the flex-basis. IE and Safari can do some weird things without it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1 0 auto;` to `.content` (in css).

See [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNmazg).

From michaPau's comment. Doing it on his behalf so this question can be resolved since he was unresponsive, and for the solution to be more accessible/explicit to people looking for it.